# How to use Pull Request properly ? (git / bitbucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to git. I'm using SourceTree client (bitbucket). 
I've cloned a repository, created some development branch from the master. Now, I will be creating branches from that development branch for each task I'm going to be writing.

The idea is that the examiner can see and and review/examine my tasks from his computer. 
Do I need to create pull requests for each 'feature'/'task' branch to the development branch?
Or do I just make pull request from development to master?

I've tried reading some Git tutorials I've found on web and they just confused me even more..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the reviewer to look at each feature separately, you are probably better off creating one pull request for each feature. If on the other hand you want them to look at all your changes simultaneously, then you might as well create one big pull request.

In the former case, you probably want to create your feature branches directly from `master` instead of creating your own `development` branch first, since in this scenario the `development` branch would not have much of a purpose and would likely just be confusing.